# Hive escape characters (\\) are causing Mismatched token exception error

Tags: hive, escaping, hiveql

I have a hive field in which data is stored in this format.

```
co_mx
["2.00","7570180962446"]
[3,"7566180246570"]
[6,"7577182138618"]
[10.00,"7573181367421"]
[10,"7573181433469"]
```

I want to extract the 2nd element in the list i.e. the larger string of numbers.

When I run the code in Hive cli terminal, I use just two escape characters (\) and it works but I found that when using `hive -e` to run the code then i have to use 4 escape characters yet the bold part of the code i.e. the `then` part of the case statement is causing some problems which i am not able to debug.

```
select 
cast(
trim(case 
when instr(split(split(co_mx,'\\\\,')[1],'\\\\]')[0],'\\\\"')>0 then 
     **split(split(split(co_mx,'\\\\,')[1],'\\\\]')[0],'\\\\"')[1]**
else split(split(co_mx,'\\\\,')[1],'\\\\]')[0] 
end)
as string) as id
from input_table
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: what is the datatype of the column in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to shield `,`. This should work fine: `split(co_mx,',')`

You can use `[]` in many cases for shielding like this: `'[\"]'` - escape here is for using in the shell. Single escape is enough for shell in this case.
Use `rlike` instead of `instr`.

Your sentence rewritten:

```
select 
cast(
trim(case 
         when MyStr rlike '[\"]' then split(MyStr,'[\"]')[1]
         else MyStr 
     end)
as string) as id
from (select s.*, 
             split(split(co_mx,',')[1],'[]]')[0] MyStr 
       from input_table s
     ) s
```